# Is there a way to create a button in discord server on bot ready?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a button in discord channel upon bot ready and without a command. It's like sending a button in the channel and then wait listening for the interaction. After successfull interaction, I want to invoke a function in my python code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot Is Online")
  channel = bot.get_channel()
  await channel.send('!menu')

  
class Menu(discord.ui.View):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.value = None

  @discord.ui.button(label="Purchase", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
  async def menu1(self, interaction: discord.Interaction,
                  button: discord.ui.Button):
    await interaction.response.send_message(
      "Purchase bot has starting ordering your product in bulk...")


@bot.command()
async def menu(ctx):
  view = Menu()
  await ctx.reply(view=view)

bot.run()
```

Comment: Currently, I have to invoke the button using "!menu" command in the channel.

Comment: Why not just create an instance of the view in `on_ready` and send that with the `channel.send` command? `await channel.send(view=view)`? Just move the creation of the `Menu` class above the defining of the `on_ready` event.

Comment: Don't make API calls in `on_ready`, do this in a startup task instead.